navigator.clipboard.writeText insert \r before \n
When I use navigator.clipboard.writeText in windows, just like
navigator.clipboard.writeText('a\nb');

Then read from clipboard
navigator.clipboard.readText();

The result will become to a\r\nb. How can I avoid the behaviour?

You could replace “carriage return + line feed” with just line feed using String.replaceAll or similar.  read more

@James Sorry I didn't explain it in enough detail. I’m using clipboard text on another website that I didn’t create. , so I can't change the text via js.

Please clarify what you can change as the comment above states you can't change anything - so it's unclear what you are asking.

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40873740
